# Remove letters when using UTF-8 in python

Tags: python, utf-8, nlp, python-unicode, farsi

I face a weird problem when I use UTF-8 and the Persian language in python.
When I want concat two strings with half-space ('\u200c') the last letter of the second word has been removed.

Here is an example:
"ماشین+\u200c+ها" should be "ماشین‌ها"  but it will be "ماشین‌ه"

It's my code:

```
name = 'ماشین'
postfix = 'ها'
name = name + '\u200c' + postfix
print(name)
//expected output: ماشین‌ها
//output: ماشین‌ه
```

Comment: It works fine for me! No issue

Comment: Try with a different font. It is possible that it is a font bug

Comment: works ok for me as well. Which python version do you use?